# Reversal of excess fat in men by increase in testosterone

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, testosterone, male, gender-specific

An increase in testosterone can reverse the excess fat.
As the men age I believe that decrease in testosterone causes fat gain.

If we increase testosterone can we reverse the extra fat storage in the body?

If yes how can we increase testosterone?